# How to insert Hindi (Other Language) characters in database

Tags: java, utf-8

How to insert Hindi words/characters into database .. While entering Hindi words from jsp  they are getting encoded in controller . I need to stop encoding so for that i have used UTF-8 & UTF-16 but also they are getting encoded.. I need to save same as Hindi Format in DB..The following is the snippet plz help me out..

```
//controller(Sample.java)

@RequestMapping(value = "/createContentforCp", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes="application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-16")
    public ModelAndView createContentForCp(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            @RequestParam("desc") String desc)throws Exception{
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-16");
System.out.println("description================"+desc)
ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView("create-content-meta");
return modelview;
}

o/p:
description====================à¤?à¤°à¤?à¥?à¤¤à¥?à¤°à¥? enter code here

While am displaying that description in console it is getting encoded and saving the same in database.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the **URLDecoder.decode()** and **URLEncoder.encode()** classes from java.net:

```
URLDecoder.decode("String with Hindi characters", "UTF-8");
URLEncoder.encode("String with Hindi characters", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Hi , Used the above while using decode() giving response as à¤?à¤ªà¤¡à¤¾ and when using encode() getting response as the format  %C3%A0%C2%A4%C2%95%C3%A0%C2%A4%C2%AA%C3%A0%C2%A4%C2%A1%C3%A0%C2%A4%C2%BE . But not displaying in Hindi characters.